# C++ static constructor returning a container

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, static, return-value

```
class Foo
{
  public:
  static std::vector<std::string> Foo(std::string x, std::string y);
};
```

I have been requested to implement a method as shown in the above code; they have provided to me only the prototype.

BUT, as you can see, it is not whichever method. It is the constructor.

I know that in C++ we can find a workaround (with nested classes or others), to have a static constructor.

But what I have never seen in my life is a constructor returning (in this case) a vector container.

Is this possible in C++?

Or, maybe, I am misunderstanding the code?

Comment: I think its a mistake .Constructor cant return and cant be static.

Comment: That code is **illegal** in C++.

Answer (score 2):

No, the code is invalid C++. Please try compiling the code, the compiler will tell you exactly what is wrong:

```
error: return type specification for constructor invalid
   static std::vector<std::string> Foo(std::string x, std::string y);
                                                                   ^
error: constructor cannot be static member function
```

Answer (score 1):

That code is *illegal* in C++, and no C++ compiler will compile that.

- A constructor is *special member-function*
- A constructor has **no** return type
- A constructor has **no** name, and hence cannot have its address taken
- Special member functions cannot be `static`

Answer (score 1):

Answers are correct: **a Constructor cannot return.**

Additional few points:

@Paul. Actually, a static constructor can be emulated, in C++. There are several posts about this topic here, in StackOverflow.

@Paul and @WhiZTiM: A Static constructor not only can be emulated, but also can be legally used in C++, for instance, in a well designed Singleton implementation.

I will not discuss here about one dozen of Singleton implementations, which are not thread-safe.

But, with the features introduced by C++11 (call_once, once_flag) you can implement a thread-safe Singleton and, for that purpose, you will need also a static Constructor (which must be private, along with a private Copy Constructor and its corresponding assignment operator).

Answer (score 0):

The constructor cannot be static. If it were it would not be able to access members of the class to initialize them, which is the purpose of the constructor.

Why not use a standalone function?